# Installing Ruby 2.4 on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, ruby, redmine

I installed CentOS 7.4 minimal setup on my system.

My next task is to setup Redmine. It needs ruby language. For Redmine version 3.4.x and future maintenance, I think it would be better to install ruby 2.4 or higher.

The problem is, CentOS' default repository still only supports ruby 2.0.

**I want to know which repository supports ruby 2.4 and also ruby-devel, ruby-irb, ruby-rdoc, ruby-ri and rails 4.2, which supports ruby 2.4.**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You might try using [RVM](https://rvm.io/).

### 1. Install RVM

From the [documentation page](https://rvm.io/)

> Install GPG keys:
>
> ```
> gpg2 --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
> ```
>
> In case you encounter an issues or want to know more, check security
>   Install RVM:
>
> ```
> \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
> ```
>
> **Follow the extra configuration information** like adding your user to the `rvm` group and executing `source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh`.

### 2. Install Ruby 2.4

After installing RVM you can just write:

```
rvm install 2.4.3
```